# How to \setstretch relative to the previous call?

Tags: setspace

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \setstretch{1.2}
  \begin{center}
    \setstretch{0.9} // here I need it to become 0.9 * 1.2
  \end{center}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `figure` environment should never be inside a `center` environment. Please, fix the request.

Comment: this seems a very strange request, as is having nested `center` environments, what is the actual use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a `\setrelativestretch` command using `xfp` facilities for the computations with floating points.

The trick is that the current factor is stored in `\baselinestretch`, but we need to ensure it is expanded before calling `\setstretch`.

In the example I have exaggerated the factors just to make the result more evident.

After the inner `\end{center}` the stretch factor will automatically return to its previous value.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xfp}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newcommand{\setrelativestretch}[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\setstretch{\fpeval{(#1)*(\baselinestretch)}}%
  }\x
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setstretch{1.5}
\lipsum[3][1-5]
\begin{center}
\setrelativestretch{0.7}
\lipsum[4][1-5]
\end{center}
\lipsum[5][1-5]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A conceptually better solution using `expl3` features:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \yegor_setstretch:n \setstretch
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \yegor_setstretch:n { e }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setrelativestretch}{m}
 {
  \yegor_setstretch:e { \fp_eval:n {(#1)*(\baselinestretch)} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setstretch{1.5}
\lipsum[3][1-5]
\begin{center}
\setrelativestretch{0.7}
\lipsum[4][1-5]
\end{center}
\lipsum[5][1-5]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I define an alias for `\setstretch` so I can also define a variant for it that first expands its argument.